# What does 「もっともな気がする」 mean?

Tags: phrases

I am reading an article by Siratori Kazuhisa, and I am struggling to find an equivalent for 「もっともな気がする」 in English. The context is as follows:

> なんとなく**もっともな気がするが**、大学の英語の試験は英語で 道を尋ねられた時にまごつかないようにするためのうすっぺらの実用英
>   語のテストではないのである

最も－most; extremely　(adverb)

もっともな（尤も）　- something being understandable/reasonable

気がする　- to have a hunch/feeling

Would it be correct in the above text to translate as follows: "I feel it reasonable but..."?

Any help understanding the meaning and intention is very much appreciated.

Comment: So I assume you looked up もっともな in the dictionary, and you looked up 気がする in the dictionary. What understanding did you gain from this? Unless you show some effort, this is quite straightforward "translate this for me" request.

Comment: You are correct, I did look these up in a dictionary, but I wasn't able to make them fit the context. Therefore I believed that もっともな気がするmay have been an idiomatic phrase, thus sought further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should have provided the preceding sentence(s) in asking this question because that is what 「もっともな気がする」 would refer to.

「もっともな気がする」 means that what was stated before it seems reasonable, justifiable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

See if seeing it in some other usages makes it easier to put together:

ケンは僕らのなかでも早く走りました。

Then add the なんとなく

酔っ払っていても、なんとなく帰ってきた。

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, it's not the なんとなくthat is the issue for me. It is the もっともな気がするが which I bolded in my original question and in the subject title. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: just realised that's the wrong 最も！ sorry.

Comment: Just realised that's the wrong 最も！ sorry. "I find it reasonable that our English should be tested in order to avoid being dumbfounded upon questioning."  ( but it has the nuance in Japanese that the writer feels most of what was on the test is/was unnecessary a common sentiment here).  Your "I feel it reasonable but..." is a good interpretation.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for the advice now we have the right もっとも！